# In nested react navigation, extra header space is coming at top

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Extra empty header space is coming at top of screen

I tried making header null for posts screen but empty space is still coming for the other two screens.

[image]

```
 const Posts=createStackNavigator({
    Posts:{screen:createMaterialTopTabNavigator(screens,{
                        tabBarOptions: {
                          scrollEnabled: true,
                        },
                        animationEnabled:false,
                      })},
    VideoDetailScreen:{screen:VideoDetail},
    NewsDetailScreen:{screen:NewsDetail},
  });

  const AppContainer = createAppContainer(Posts);
```

Answer (score 3):

I fixed following [this workaround](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/3184#issuecomment-403488809) by adding an option to `navigationOptions` as follows:

```js
navigationOptions: {
    ...
    headerForceInset: { top: 'never', bottom: 'never' },
},
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use StatusBar with translucent options, you need to use in your screenOptions on Stack.Navigator, the option headerStatusBarHeight: 0

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69213691/7641774

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass headerMode:'none'

```py
export default StackNavigator({
    LoginScreen: { screen: Login.component }
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'LoginScreen',
    headerMode: 'none' 
})
```

Comment: This isn't much use when you do want a header.  The problem is the spacing, not the header itself.